# How to save multiple images data in single row and how to get it

Tags: php, mysql

It is code for multiple images upload.

```
include("../includes/db_connect.php");
$c=count($_FILES[image_name][name]);
if($c<=5)
{
    for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
    {
        $img=$_FILES[image_name][name][$i];
        if($img)
        {
            $img_arr=explode(".",$img);
            $img=$img_arr[0].".".$img_arr[1];
            $img_size=$_FILES[image_name][size][$i]/1024;
            $img_type=$_FILES[image_name][type][$i];
            $img_ext=$img_arr[1];
            $sql="INSERT INTO  `university`.`gallary` (`image_name` ,`image_size` ,`image_type` ,`image_ext`)VALUES ( '$img',  '$img_size',  '$img_type',  '$img_ext');";
        }
        $rs=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[image_name][tmp_name][$i],"../uploads/gallary/".$_FILES[image_name][name][$i]);
    }
    header("location:../gallary_view.php?msg=Image Uploaded Successfully!!!");
}
else
{
    header("location:../gallary_add.php?msg=Please Upload 5 Image For One Time");
}
?>
```

After this it is creating single row for each image data. I want this in single row.How to do it?

Comment: The system you have is the correct one. Each image in it's own row is the correct way to go. multiple images in a row would be to break a working system.

Comment: Don't create columns for duplicate data, create single row per image

Comment: You would need to redefine your table to have as many columns as you require images - but if that number could vary it is not the best idea. If you need them grouped add another column that can contain a unique identifier for that group of images.

Comment: Just use a foreign key to distinguish images

Comment: make a new column in the table for their common data like user_id, news_id, blabla_id, after that you can select them with that id so you dont need them to in one row

Comment: I am using this code for single user in matrimonial website and i tried many things please help to give the code example or table

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Save everything in new row and afrer use group_concat to get it in same row

Comment: @Oncodeeater it is working for single image information but not remain 4

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I am new in php and learning everything I know what is pdo but how to use it dont know

Comment: http://www.jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html

Comment: If you can post your select query, that would help

Comment: @Oncodeeater  <?php
  $sql="select * from gallary";
  $i=0;
  $rs=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
  {
   $i++;
   ?>

    <td><img src="uploads/gallary/<?php echo $data[image_name];?>" height="100" width="120"></td> 
 
  <?php
 
  }
  ?>

Comment: oh.. I see now what you want to do, if u want to put everything out in the same row you could GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT CONCAT(image_name,',', image_id,',',andsoon) 
  ORDER BY image_id
  SEPARATOR ';'
), but i guess you just want to save all info in same row in database, there is no point in that rly because you would need to explode it later it is not safe nor good, and it would just break everything, but if u would do something like that u would need something that is called table transpose or pivot. But don't do it just save it the way you did.

Comment: It is required in my project suggest please anyother idea to do it @Oncodeeater

Comment: I am doing this for user profile picture where user save four images and after that in profile picture it will show randomly

Comment: Then you need one more tablen, one for users and  that one will be related to img table, and when you are calling that user id, you call img from table, they dont have to be in same row in table for them to be displayed as such, but again if you want them to be in same row when you get them you need to group_concat, and you need sql select with join so you can join those tables you have(will have). But again they dont need to be in same row in database to be displayed in same row, because you are using php just do it after you pull them from db

Comment: Thanks @Oncodeeater

Answer (score 0):

Its possible. You can have the multiple images or files in single row of database.
This is the method I'm using to get multiple images and storing them in single row of DB.

Firstly Make a folder named "images" to save uploaded images also in folder.

Make a file "index.php" & paste this code inside:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Multiple Images in Single Row</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">. 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
    $('#form').submit(function(event){
        var formdata = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url:'image_upload.php',
            data: formdata,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            type: "POST", 
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Something went wrong!")
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make another file named "image_upload.php" to save both in folder & DB.

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "singlerowmultipleimgs";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db;","$username","$pass");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$targetDir = "images/";
$image = $_FILES['files']['name'];
$fileName = implode(",", $image);
// echo $fileName;
if(!empty($image)){
foreach ($image as $key => $val) {
    $targetfilepath = $targetDir . $val;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key], 
    $targetfilepath);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO images(images) VALUES('$fileName')";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
echo "Image uploaded Successfully";
}
?>
```

Make a DB, named "singlerowmultipleimgs". Make a table inside named "images" in it.
Make 2 fields named id and images like the image given below.
[image]

Here's the directory files flow:
[image]

I hope it helped!